# Spring integration chain error handling

Tags: spring, spring-integration

Need help in error handling in a chain during splitter and aggregator flow for a synchronous channel.
Below is the Use case and it will be synchronous channel. So in the chain there will be a set of service activator to perform the business logic. Now if there is any exception in the service activator present in the chain, I want that to be handled in the chain itself and continue with the other splitted messages.

Inorder to do that, I have tried adding header enricher for error handler in the chain.But did not work. Any suggestion.

**Object1 contains List < Object2 >**

**Flow:**

List < Object1 > --> Splitter1 (for Object1) --> **Splitter2** (for Object2) --> **Chain** --> Aggregator --> Aggregator

**Code**

```
   <int:chain input-channel="ch3" output-channel="ch10"  >
      <int:header-enricher>
        <int:error-channel  ref="exception1" ></int:error-channel>
    </int:header-enricher>

   <int:service-activator ref="myService" method="method1"></int:service-activator>

   <int:service-activator ref="myService" method="method2"></int:service-activator>
   <int:service-activator ref="myService" method="method3"></int:service-activator>
    <int:service-activator ref="myService" method="method4"></int:service-activator>
</int:chain>


    <!-- Exception channel for chain and the output should go to the chain output channel -->     
    <int:chain input-channel="exception1" output-channel="ch10"  >
        <int:service-activator ref="exp" method="myException"></int:service-activator>  
    </int:chain>
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it doesn't work that way. The `error-channel` header is for the asynchronous cases, too. It allows to override the default behavior in the `MessagePublishingErrorHandler` for `PollableChannel` and channels with `Executor`. In other words when we really can't do `try...catch` if talk in raw Java words.

So, to fix your requirements you really should rely on the `try...catch` function for that particular `<service-activator>`. It is called like `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` and must be configured as on the [`<request-handler-advice-chain>`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#message-handler-advice-chain).

In your case you should configure that `Advice` like:

```
<bean class="ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
    <property name="trapException" value="true"/>
    <property name="onFailureExpression" value="#exception"/>
    <property name="failureChannel" value="myErrorChannel"/>
</bean>
```

The `trapException="true"` allows do not re-throw the exception to the top level. In your case to the `<splitter>`.

The `onFailureExpression` says what to send to the `failureChannel` from the `catch` block.

The `failureChannel` is your desired `error-channel` to handle `<service-activator>` failures.

The source code looks like, by the way:

```
   try {
        Object result = callback.execute();
        if (this.onSuccessExpression != null) {
            this.evaluateSuccessExpression(message);
        }
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Exception actualException = this.unwrapExceptionIfNecessary(e);
        if (this.onFailureExpression != null) {
            Object evalResult = this.evaluateFailureExpression(message, actualException);
            if (this.returnFailureExpressionResult) {
                return evalResult;
            }
        }
        if (!this.trapException) {
            throw actualException;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Since we prevent re-throw with `trapException="true"`, we end up on the `return null`. And having `<service-activator>` with `null-payload` loyalty we allow our `<splitter>` to go ahead with other messages.

HTH

Comment: Thanks. I have implemented as per the above comment.

Comment: Glad to hear! Would be a good tone to accept the question for other community members. You are welcome, BTW!